# How do I prevent JQuery's val() from dropping everything after a whitespace?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm writing something that fetches states and cities dynamically, based on select values. If, for example,a user chooses "United States" as a country, the page sends a query via AJAX to the server and populates `States` with "Ohio", "Alabama", "Florida" and so on. When the user chooses "Florida" it will populate the `Cities` dropdown with "Orlando", "Miami" and so on.

I listen for changes using `$().change`. When a change is detected, I get the value from the select field with `$().val()`.

```
     País: <select name="country" id="newCompCountry"></select>
 - Estado: <select name="state" id="newCompState"></select>
 - Ciudad: <select name="city" id="newCompCity"></select><br />
```

The option tags are populated like so:

```
$.get("../process/getCountries.php",  function(data){
        var countries = $("#newCompCountry");
        countries.empty();
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            countries.append("<option value=" + data[i] +">"+ data[i] +"</option>");
        }
    }, "json");

    $.get("../process/getStates.php", {country_name : $("#newCompCountry").val()}, function(data){
        var states = $("#newCompState");
        states.empty();
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            states.append("<option value=" + data[i] +">"+ data[i] +"</option>");
        }
        console.log("ESTADO: " + $("#newCompState").val());
    }, "json");

    $.get("../process/getCities.php", {country_name : $("#newCompCountry").val(), state_name : $("#newCompState").val()}, function(data){
        var cities = $("#newCompCity");
        cities.empty();
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            cities.append("<option value=" + data[i] +">"+ data[i] +"</option>");
        }
    }, "json");
```

The thing is, when I grab the .val() from any field, and that .val() happens to have spaces, everything is dropped when the space is detected.

Take for example my country. I live in "Bolivia", in the department of "La Paz", in the city of "La Paz". When I grab the value of "La Paz", it just comes out as "La".

This is a problem, because the database holds city names with spaces and a few other special characters you may find in other peculiar cities. Is there a way to force jquery to not drop anything after a whitespace is detected?

Here's a screenshot to show you what I mean (this is the log you can find in the code above):

[image: "La"]

Any help you can give me will be really appreciated.

Comment: What is your php output like? Proper JSON shouldn't drop anything.

Comment: Do you want me to post the script or just console.log the data after the $.get is executed?

Comment: Go to the network tab, find the proper AJAX call and paste its response.

Comment: A'ight, the response is simply an array: ["La Paz","Santa Cruz","Cochabamba"]

Comment: is the array wrapped in curly brackets? i.e. `{}`

Comment: Nope, it's wrapped inside the square brackets. Here's a quick screenshot of the Network tab: http://i42.tinypic.com/csq9z.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the rendered HTML:

```
<option value=La Paz>La Paz</option>
```

Now do you see the problem?

Try adding quotes. Alternatively, use [vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/):

```
var states = document.getElementById("newCompState");
states.options.length = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    states.appendChild(new Option(data[i]));    
}
```

Comment: *Plants face on desk*. Really need to look at my output closely and carefully time. Thank you sir, you are today's hero.

Comment: Quick question. While the constructor of Option create an option tag that has ``data[i]`` as both it's content and value? Or just content?

Comment: Im used to the document.createElement('option') approach, dont know if Option is present in all DOM browsers engines

Comment: @AndyIbanez Yes. Well, actually no, it will create `<option>DATA HERE</option>`, but since it's clearly defined that options with no value attribute default to their text, it's the same thing just more efficient ;) If you want, you can use `new Option(data[i],data[i])` just to be absolutely explicit that you want them to be the same.

Comment: @Roger It is. Just like `new Image`, for example.

Comment: Thanks for this... I just spent forever trying to figure this out. All I was missing was some quotes.